# AS3 : how to back from inside of movie clip to main frame

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a movie clip (symbol 2) inside another movie clip on the main frame. I want to get back to the main timeline in frame 2 when the movie clip is finish to play (frame 200). Then I do this on my last movie clip frame (frame 200) :

```
MovieClip(root).gotoAndStop(2);
```

It works, I go to the main frame (frame 2) but I also get an error:

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null
>   object reference.     at
>   hehe_fla::Symbol2_2/frame200()[hehe_fla.Symbol2_2::frame200:1]

Comment: Try and be more specific, does it work at all?  show your mouse click function,  is the gotoAndStop call on frame 200 of symbol 2? or is some other code there?

Comment: I just want to get back to my main frame, when the movie clip is over (frame 200)

Comment: Are you stopping your symbol 2 timeline after goto?

Comment: Can you post your fla?

Comment: thanks sir... I already finish it, It's only need the
import flash.Media.MovieClip;
i got it, thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you should do like this : ( comments are in the code )

```
symbol_2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(e){

    trace(e.currentTarget.name)             // trace the name of symbol_2, gives you of course symbol_2
    trace(e.currentTarget.parent.name)      // trace the name of the parent of symbol_2, gives the name of your object (the parent clip of symbole_2)

    trace(e.currentTarget.root.name)        // trace the name of the root of symbol_2 : root1
    trace(e.currentTarget.parent.root.name) // trace the name of the root of the parent of symbol_2 : root1
                                            // here you should get the same name, because it's the same root
                                            // and that's why we can do like this : 

    e.currentTarget.root.gotoAndStop(2)
                                            // or like this, to go to and stop in the frame 2 of root

    e.currentTarget.parent.root.gotoAndStop(2)

})
```

Comment: Unless the context of the mouse click handler is not on the display list, this is just a convoluted way of doing the same thing as `MovieClip(root).gotoAndStop(2)`.

Comment: Do you think that if `MovieClip(root).gotoAndStop(2)` worked, you will have this question here ?

Comment: I see, but who told you that your `MovieClip(root).gotoAndStop(2)` works ? because your error is fired here `hehe_fla.Symbol2_2::frame200:` in the frame 200 of `Symbol2_2` so when you do `MovieClip(root).gotoAndStop(2)`. To be sure, can you show us the code that you run in the frame 200 of your `Symbol2_2` ?

Comment: that was the code :
MovieClip(root).gotoAndStop(2);
it was on frame 200.. can you please help me...